# Connect and Sync 2 Mysql Databases

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization

Is it possible to sync 2 MYSQL databases so if you write into one it will sync add it to the other one too and other way around? I've seen some Programs that you can use on your local pc but I need a script for example php that I can upload to my vps, it checks every minute for new data and syncs it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried Mysql Replication strategies? See [MySQL Replication for High Availability](https://severalnines.com/resources/database-management-tutorials/mysql-replication-high-availability-tutorial).

Specially Master with Backup Master (Multiple Replication)
[image]

or Master with Active Master (Circular Replication or Ring topology)
[image]